# cleaning up vars in finalize and dealloc

Tags: cocoa, garbage-collection

**Is there a method that is called before finalize that I can use for cleanup like I normally use dealloc for?**

With GarbageCollection off, in the dealloc method, I do cleanup like setting public, retained, instance vars 
to nil (that will release and set the pointer to nil).

Apple says you shouldn't do that in the the finalize method if you turn on GC.

Let's say I make an NSView subclass with a retained NSTimer property. In order to make sure that timer is invalidated, I need to call invalidate on it before/while the subclass is deallocated. With GC off, I just say [self.time invalidate] and set it to nil in the dealloc method.

With GC on however, it seems the only way to do this is make an IBOulet to the view subclass. Then, before I remove the view I need to invalidate the timer.

I would prefer not to have to make outlets for all my custom views or controls...Is there a better or more automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If you have a custom control and you have vars that retain something. You need to create an outlet to that control and clean up the vars that you retained.